# How to show a message if SQL search query failed to find values

Tags: c#

I'm trying to show a "Login failed" message if SQL query failed to find a match for username and password inputs.

At the moment "Login Success" message works perfectly. I tried some solutions but they didn't work.

```
private void tLoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Get values
        string userName = tInputUser.Text;
        string pass = tInputPass.Text;

        // Search if user exists                
        string user_search = "SELECT * FROM Teachers WHERE (emailAddr = '" + userName + "' and password = '" + pass + "')";
        SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(user_search, con);
        con.Open();

        // Excute sql command and get results to an array
        SqlDataReader result = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

        while (result.Read())
        {
            string finalUsername = result[3].ToString();
            string finalPass = result[4].ToString();

            MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do an `if(result.Read())` and then the `else` would be when there are no matches.  Also I strongly recommend that you use parameters to avoid sql injections and you really should be hashing passwords saved in a DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're query does not return any records, it does not throw an exception.  Instead, the `while (result.Read())` loop will simply not run.

You could check for results specifically with something like:

```
if (result.HasRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
}
```

or, if you need to access data from the record:

```
if (result.Read())
{
    string finalUsername = result[3].ToString();
    string finalPass = result[4].ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
}
```

I would not recommend querying with `SELECT *` and then referencing fields by their index.  It would be better to write `SELECT emailAddr, password FROM Teachers ...` and access the fields by their name, such as `result["emailAddr"]`.

Also, you have a **SQL injection vulnerability**. You should look up what this means and how to parameterize a query.

Also, it appears you are **storing passwords in plain text**.  You should look up password hashing and proper storage.

Comment: Gotta updoot when people warn others about sql injection.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly. I have parameterized the queries now, thanks for the information about SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Two things. First, you can use `SqlDataReader.HasRows` to know whether or not the query returned any results. So instead of `while (result.Read())` you can just say `if (result.HasRows)`. Then you can use an `else` for the opposite (no user found).

```c#
if (result.HasRows)
{
    // User exists
}
else
{
    // User does not exist
}
```

Second problem, you're using string concatenation to build the query. This leaves you open to SQL injection, which is no good. You should use a parameterized query instead:

```c#
string userSearch = "SELECT * FROM Teachers WHERE emailAddr = @email and password = @password";
// Create the command
cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", userName);
cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
```

You can read more about parameterized queries here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks for showing the parameterized query method as well. I didn't know it before.

Comment: I added WHERE after Teachers then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I typed this answer on my phone. I know you accepted the other answer, but I still updated mine to include the `WHERE`.